Transforming Parameter pack in template without wrapping struct
I have the following code, which works:
template <typename ...Types>
struct Wrapper
{
    template <void (*F)(typename Types::ParameterType...)>
    static void toNativeFunction(Stuff stuff)
    {
        auto arguments = toConvertedArguments<Types...>(stuff);
    
        std::apply(F, arguments);
    }
};

Where toConvertedArguments has the following declaration:
template<typename... Types>
using converted_tuple = std::tuple<typename Converter<Types>::ReturnType...>;

template<typename... Types>
converted_tuple<Types...> toConvertedArguments(Stuff stuff);

I then call it like this:

void implementation(int);

template<typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    using ParameterType = T;
}

//...
{
    Wrapper<SomeClass<int>>::toNativeFunction<&implementation>(stuff);
}

This works! But the only reason Wrapper exists is because I can't use Types... in the template function definition in the same template. My question is whether I can skip the Wrapper indirection and have something "conceptually" like this:
template <typename ...Types, void (*F)(typename Types::ParameterType...)>
static void toNativeFunction(Stuff stuff);

This of course doesn't work, since you can't have something that follows a parameter pack (or rather, this is not one of the exceptions that's allowed). I similarly can't swap the order of the template parameters:
template <void (*F)(typename Types::ParameterType...), typename ...Types>
static void toNativeFunction(Stuff stuff);

Since now it doesn't know what Types is yet. So, is there something fancy I can do to avoid the Wrapper class (maybe using an inner lambda call or something?).

auto with extra requires might do the job:
template <auto f, typename ...Types>
static void toNativeFunction(Stuff stuff)
requires (requires {
    std::apply(f, toConvertedArguments<Types...>(stuff));
})
{
    auto arguments = toConvertedArguments<Types...>(stuff);

    std::apply(f, arguments);
}

Demo

If you're okay with taking the function pointer as a regular argument rather than a template arg, you can do this:
template<typename... Wrappers>
void callNative(void(*F)(typename Wrappers::ParameterType...), Stuff stuff) {
    std::apply(F, toConvertedArguments<Wrappers...>(stuff));
} 

Called as:
callNative<SomeClass<int>>(implementation, stuff);

And if you need it to only take one arg, you can bind it:
auto implNative = std::bind_front(callNative<SomeClass<int>>, implementation);
implNative(stuff);

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/1G6qYaTx4
